# Understanding performance timings, loadingFinished vs dataReceived ordering

Tags: performance, google-chrome, http, networking, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to understand the network events of ChromeDev tools for performance analysis. I'm currently getting those events by using a Selenium Webdriver as also described [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging/performance-log):

```js
this.Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
```

Basically I'm only interested in the events

- `requestWillBeSent` (fired when page is about to send HTTP request)
- `responseReceived` (fired when HTTP response is available)
- `dataReceived` (fired when data chunk was received over the network)
- `loadingFinished` (fired when HTTP request has finished loading)

See the official docs to this [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/).

So my understanding on this is that the `loadingFinished` event always is sent as the **last** event of a request, however, sometimes a get values like this.

```js
{
  "method": "Network.loadingFinished",
  "params": {
    "encodedDataLength": 12129,
    "requestId": "1000005700.18",
    "shouldReportCorbBlocking": false,
    "timestamp": 605026.668895
  }
}

{
  "method": "Network.dataReceived",
  "params": {
    "dataLength": 0,
    "encodedDataLength": 11825,
    "requestId": "1000005700.18",
    "timestamp": 605026.671788
  }
}
```

As you see, the `loadingFinished` event has a **lower** timestamp than the `dataReceived` event.

Why is a data received event sent after the loading event?
What's the relationship between the mentioned events?

Comment: Regarding the last part of the question, [looks like](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/inspector/inspector_network_agent.cc?l=1036-1039&rcl=629c542e) it happens in DidFinishLoading() when there is a chunk of data not yet sent from the browser network fetch process to a renderer process that initiated the request.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your answer. I understand a little bit more now, however I also get responseReceived (!) messages with a higher timestamp than dataReceived messages, is this also due to the Chrome multi-process architecture?

Comment: You can verify it in chrome://tracing ([info](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool/trace-event-reading)). It may use different internal event labels though.